# Rotating text at a specific angle in Borb (PDF)

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, borb

Using Borb I'm trying to find a way to put text at a certain angle (27.33°). However, as stated in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73002719/how-to-rotate-only-table-using-borb-pdf-library-python), rotating LayoutElements is not yet possible.

I cannot rotate the page, put my text and rotate it back since my angle is so specific and I also could not figure out how to use the Transformation Matrix to do this.
Is there a simple way to achieve this and rotate my text?